# Tick character (`) randomly added when typing

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, troubleshooting

I have a microsoft wireless keyboard (wireless comfort keyboard 5000) and I'm running on Windows 7. Every once in a while, as I type, a random ` character gets added and I know it's not a typo as the ` key is out of reach.

This is so infrequent that I can live with it but it has happened often enough that I know something is up.

Has anyone ever come across this kind of issue?

Edit:

- I have changed batteries since.
- I have cleaned the keyboard

Comment: Have you tried new batteries?

Comment: This has been ongoing for a long time. I've switched the batteries between events and currently my low battery light isn't on. Would a low battery cause this issue consistently (adding a tick over any other character)?

Comment: Also turn your computer key-side down and shake, maybe tap it a few times?

Comment: It could do just about anything, usually random or missing character, but I had to ask. :)  The next thing to confirm is possible interference, have you tried relocating the receiver (away from fans, monitors, radios, etc.)?  If you have a list of things you've tried already, please edit your question to include them and their results, that way we don't have to ask you about stuff you've already tried. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried cleaning out the keyboard and I don't think my keyboard could be any closer to the bluetooth dongle (my machine is a laptop on my desk, using a keyboard so I can have dual monitors). It happens so rarely that it's difficult to troubleshoot :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong about it, but considering its a wireless keyboard you may be suffering interference from another radio wave emitter, such as remote controls, car keys, cellphones, etc. As the incident is always with the same character, this might be the problem, but I'm not quite sure. try switching off or even placing any kind of radio wave emitter somewhere 'out of reach' of the dongle.

Hope to help.